# not able to get current term id if url contains variables

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get current term id on a woocommerce category page.
I am only able to get the term id only if the url does not contain variables like:

```
?swoof=1&product_cat=femmes,bijoux&page=1
```

It works for http://www.example.com/categorie-produit/femmes.

I need to get femmes category ID.

but not for `http://www.example.com/categorie-produit/femmes/?swoof=1&product_cat=femmes,bijoux&page=1`

I am using the following code to get the term id:

```
get_queried_object()->term_id
```

I need to get femmes category ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following code

```
$categoryIds = get_query_var('product_cat');
$cats        = explode(',',$categoryIds);
$cat_obj     = get_term_by('slug', $cats[0] , 'product_cat');
$categoryID  = $cat_obj->term_id;
```

In $categoryIds You will get all categories from parent to child.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer!